# CSS .class a {} not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This algorithm just stopped working on my page (it had worked for over a year as it was):

```
<div class="classA" id="specific1">
    <a href="#">Link Text</a>
</div>

.classA a {
    style: actual style;
}
```

The a tag no longer picks up the style in the css. Now in order for my a tags to pick up the style I have to give them a class specifically and this works:

```
<div class="classA" id="specific1">
    <a class="classB" href="#">Link Text</a>
</div>
```

Did something change recently in IE7 or FireFox4 that would break the first algorithm? I'd prefer to fix the css rather than inserting a class onto all of the relevant a tags on several pages.

Edit to show better the actual styling:

This no longer works (links have vanilla 100%-blue-underline styling) but had been working for quite some time. Note that it was first designed for IE6, survived the switch to IE7, but has subsequently stopped picking up its style. Hopefully this helps all of you who have graciously tried to answer!

```
-- HTML --
<div class="ovalButton" id="oval1"><a href="#">LinkText</a></div>       

-- CSS --
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

.ovalButton {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
}

.ovalbutton a {
    background: url("logo_butn.gif") no-repeat;
    display: block;
    color: #0063B5;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px 15px 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.ovalbutton a:Hover { background: url("logo_butn_highlight.gif") no-repeat; }

#oval1 { top: 12px; left: 300px; }
#oval1 a { padding-top: 25px; }
```

When I copy the exact styling from .ovalbutton a {} to a separate class and apply that class to the link in the html, it works fine.

Comment: 2 points: above you have HTML/CSS, not an algorithm and CSS needs to be wrapped in <style> tags or else inline.

Comment: Perhaps you have new styles overwriting it?

Comment: `style` is not a valid CSS property.... Please post your actual HTML, CSS (relevant part).

Comment: Could you link to your problem website or at least to a test page?

Comment: haha, Felix, neither is `actual style;` a CSS property

Comment: @Phil: I felt I had to say something ;) What can you do with pseudocode in this case? Nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments: I didn't include the actual HTML and CSS because it's inside my company. I only meant to show the patterns that weren't working anymore. I'll use a better example next time!

Comment: "recently in IE7 or FireFox4" ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Edited to address some of the comments above. Hope that's better!

Comment: @Angie: Please see my updated answer in response to your posted code. There is a capitalization error in your CSS selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.ovalbutton a {
```

The capitalization does not match:

```
<div class="ovalButton"
```

You can change your CSS selector to `.ovalButton a` to fix this problem.

Comment: Wow. It's always the little things. That did it, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your full CSS, I can't say for sure, but it sounds likely that you are running into a [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/) issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code as entered in your question is that the capitilisation on the class and CSS selector is different

```
ovalbutton vs ovalButton
```

you can see this corrected and working at http://jsfiddle.net/5aKKR/1/ (no background images)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, are you sure that the `CSS selector`, `.classA a`, is the problem? [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/n7S4G/)

Comment: Yeah, this should work.  Maybe it is a style that is no longer supported.

Comment: I think so; I can't think of a way to test that other than the fact that giving it a specific style works (therefore the CSS link isn't the problem, etc.) What really has me stumped is that it just stopped working like a switch got turned off, and that it's ONLY the a tags that dropped their styling.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed in this respect and your selector should work.

Try to reproduce your problem on separate page and you will see.